# WSL 2- Does the root user in WSL 2 have admin privileges on Windows

Tags: windows, wsl-2

I believe this not the case i.e. being root in WSL 2 gives no admin privileges on the Windows system though I would love to have confirmation.

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can do a test.My computer was shut down and the administrator confirmed that I could not test it. It is not possible to modify the host file directly, you can modify the host file directly from root in WSL to confirm whether it has permissions.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`